# Como bloquear usuário de voltar à página anterior do navegador

Tags: javascript

**Existe algum método que faça com que um usuário não consiga retornar a página anterior?**

Acontece que tenho um formulário de contato no qual a pessoa deve preencher e pronto. Que não seja possível ela retornar e preencher novamente.

É como se a guia do navegador criasse uma nova seção, ou algo do tipo.

> É possível fazer com que seja "bloqueado" a opção voltar à página anterior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este script substituirá as tentativas de navegar para frente e para trás com o estado da página atual.

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
```

O **pushState** altera o referrer que é usado no cabeçalho HTTP para objetos XMLHttpRequest criados depois de alterar o estado.

[Veja mais sobre.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Note que esse código não é **cross-browser**, use por sua responsabilidade.

## ATUALIZAÇÃO

O método pushState é compatível com

```
Chrome - 5 >
Firefox (Gecko) - 4.0 (2.0) >
Internet Explorer - 10 >
Opera - 11.50 >
Safari - 5.0 >
```

Comment: Esse código está certo? Você disse pushState, mas no código está popstate.

Comment: Eu me referi ao método pushState.

Comment: Vou testar agora!

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Qual versão do seu navegador e qual navegador ?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Maxthon Cloud Browser, ele tem algum problema de incompactibilidade com algum navegador?